# Playing random sounds continuously on the page

Tags: javascript, html, variables, audio

Consider:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <audio>
        </audio>

        <script language="javascript">
            var playlist = new Array;
                playlist[0] = "sounds/0.mp3";
                playlist[1] = "sounds/1.mp3";
                playlist[2] = "sounds/2.mp3";
            var song = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
            song.innerHTML = '<source src="' + playlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length)] + '" type="audio/mpeg">';
            song.autoplay = true;

            document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(song)
            {
                <!-- Play another random song -->
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to make a very simple page which is going to play random songs continuously. But I couldn't figure it out. It plays just one random song and stops. By the way I am going to extend the song list. This is just a prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I changed:

1. Refactored how you define your list
2. Created a function to choose a new song (It doesn't pick the last played song)
3. Changed `getElementsByTag()` to `getElementById()`
4. For *debugging* I added controls

Code:

```html
<audio id="audioplayer" controls> <!-- Remove the "Controls" Attribute if you don't want the visual controls -->
</audio>

<script>
    var lastSong = null;
    var selection = null;
    var playlist = ["sounds/0.mp3", "sounds/1.mp3", "sounds/2.mp3"]; // List of songs
    var player = document.getElementById("audioplayer"); // Get audio element
    player.autoplay=true;
    player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); // Run function when the song ends

    function selectRandom(){
        while(selection == lastSong){ // Repeat until a different song is selected
            selection = Math.floor(Math.random() * playlist.length);
        }
        lastSong = selection; // Remember the last song
        player.src = playlist[selection]; // Tell HTML the location of the new song
    }

    selectRandom(); // Select initial song
    player.play(); // Start song
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't play any song. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thank you. This time, it played a song and then stopped.

Comment: Thank you Oisin. Of course I do so if it works but I am sorry to say that it is still doing the same thing with my code.

Comment: Now, it is not even playing a song

Comment: I forgot to chage you playlist back... derp

Comment: No Problem! Before you go I just want to make sure you know how my Code works, if not it won't help you at all.

Comment: I also want to know that how it works. I'm on it. Let me check the code

Comment: @Caglar I have added some comments :)

Comment: Now it is more easy to see what happens. Thank you for your all help Oisin.