# How to play randomly chosen music using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have button that changes when you press play/pause and I was wondering how should I make it play song randomly.

```
<a id="play-pause-button" class="fa fa-play"></a>
<script>
var audio = new Audio("audio link");

$('#play-pause-button').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-play'))
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
     $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
     audio.play();
   }
  else
   {
     $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
     $(this).addClass('fa-play');
     audio.pause();
   }
});

audio.onended = function() {
     $("#play-pause-button").removeClass('fa-pause');
     $("#play-pause-button").addClass('fa-play');
};
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a list of songs somewhere on your webpage?

Comment: If you have an array of audio URLs, pick a random element of the array, then use that as the argument in `audio = new Audio(...)` before `audio.play()`

Comment: Will this questions help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635281/playing-random-sounds-continuously-on-the-page **or** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604400/play-a-random-sound-on-single-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your musics probably are in an array, to play music randomly, you have to had the length of that array, and use random function to produce random number in a specific range.(this link will help to generate your numbers: [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range))

Comment: What you wrote is very helpful to the OP, but it sounds more like a comment than an answer.